# How do I check in solidity if interface is supported?

Tags: solidity, bytes, interfaces

In the new ERC721 documents (erc721.org), the interface says that one of the functions should be:

```
        /**
        * @dev Returns `true` if the contract implements `interfaceID` and`interfaceID` is not 0xffffffff, `false` otherwise
        * @param  interfaceID The interface identifier, as specified in ERC-165
        */

        function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID) external view returns (bool);
```

Does anyone have examples of this function in use and where it pulls the interfaceId from?

I have this base code written to check that it has a function, but how do a check an entire interface?

```
function ERC721() {
    supportedInterfaces[this.supportsInterface.selector] = true;
}

function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID) external view returns (bool) {
    return supportedInterfaces[interfaceID];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're referring https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/165

This has been further developed in https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/881

The specification there says:

> We define the interface identifier as the XOR of all function selectors in the interface.

Hence, you have to do something like this:

```
supportedInterfaces[this.ifc_method_1.selector ^ ... ^ this.ifc_method_n.selector] = true;
```

Alternatively to mappings, you could just precalculate the XOR expression and use the constant value in the `supportsInterface` function:

```
function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID) external view returns (bool) {
    return interfaceID == INTERFACE_ID;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response..so what would that look like in solidity code? Would I have to use the above code for each function?

Comment: I've extended the answer. There is also example code at the end of the document behind the second link, which demonstrates the usage.

Answer (score 0):

See [OpenZeppelin's ERC165Checker](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/utils#ERC165Checker), which looks like what you need.